# Is it possible to merge two regex queries?

Tags: javascript, regex

I proceed to these two replace queries (called by javascript), to handle the case in which the color css style would be placed at the end of style attribute, with no semicolon...

```
replace(/\bstyle=["|'](.*)(?:color:.*?;)(.*)["|']/gi, 'style="$1$2"' )
replace(/\bstyle=["|'](.*)(?:color:.*["|'])/gi, 'style="$1"' )
```

It would be more pretty to merge them... However I spent hours with no success !

EDIT : here's a sample text :

`Lorem ipsum <span style="font-style:italic; color: blue; font-weight: bold;">dolor sit amet</span>, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim <span style="font-style:italic; font-weight: bold; color: blue">ad minim veniam</span>, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.`

Comment: Mind that problems can occur with this, for instance if you code `bstyle="foo" bar="color:foo"`, it will match `foo" bar="color:foo`. You better use ungreedy matches I think...

Comment: Could you please post sample text these patterns should match?

Comment: Don't try to manipulate HTML and style attributes with HTML. Use the tools and APIs provided for the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
replace(/\bstyle(=["'].*)(?:color:.*?;(.*)["']|color:[^;]*?["'])/gi, 'style$1$2');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to delete the `color` from style.
I think, rather than reconstructing the `style`, 
it would be better to delete the `color`, by

```
replace(/\bcolor:[^;'"]*;?/gi, '');       //updated from [^; ] to [^;'"]
```

it is to replace everything from `color` until `;` or `space` to `""`

Comment: Your regex doesn't catch the value after the colon.

Comment: But it works with `(?:(color:[^"']*?;)|(color:.*?)["'])`

Comment: This one :  `\bcolor:[^;"']*;?`

Comment: it doesn't catch any values; instead it replace `color:somecolor;` by `""`(empty string), and return the processed string. Which, for example, should replace `style="something1:before; color:somecolor; something2:after"` by `style="something1:before; something2:after"`

Comment: and yup, `[^;'"]` sounds better

Comment: "catch" wasn't the right term, I meant that it did not include the "somecolor" after "color:". Sorry for imprecise terms...